# Connection string as parameter of GET/POST request

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I get in my servlet as a request parameter a connection string to mysql database for example:

```
db=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baza?user=root&password=pass1234
```

And it's a problem because method `request.getParameter("db")` return only part of the connection string to `&`. The rest is interpreted as a next param. I tried use `request.getQueryString().substring(3)` but it work's only for GET request. Any idea how can I resolve my problem?

**I can't encode request!**

Answer (score 1):

The parameter value for your GET/POST request needs to be URL encoded like this:

```
db=jdbc%3Amysql%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3306%2Fbaza%3Fuser%3Droot%26password%3Dpass1234
```

You can use [sites like this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode strings that you want to pass as parameter to your GET/POST request.

Comment: But I can't encode this. I must work on plain string. Don't worry it's not real system :)

Comment: If you pass the parameter value like above, you will get the plain string when you use request.getParameter("db")